# Function to get different types of input?

Tags: c#, types, parameters

I have a `BigInt` class in C#, which has functions like

```
public BigInt Multiply(BigInt Other)
public BigInt Exponentiate(BigInt Other)
```

etc. and BigInt can be constructed with strings or ints, that's ok to have more than one constructors. But when I want to call these arithmetic functions with int's (instead of BigInt's) like

```
this.Multiply(int a);
```

I have to re-define the same Multiply function with input int like

```
public BigInt Multiply(int other)
{
BigInt Other = new BigInt(other);
//rest of the code same
}
```

so how can I handle this in one piece of code?
I think default parameters will allow only one of these (e.g. just BigInt but not int or vice versa).

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If this is not a homework, use `System.Numerics.BigInteger`.

Comment: Wow, didn't know this existed. If this was a homework I probably would :) thanks anyway.

Comment: @marvin it seems you misunderstood. L.B is saying that reimplementing `BigInteger` yourself is a bad idea unless you *have to* do it.

Comment: ok, but I have already reimplemented it. so why not finish it :)

Answer (score 3):

Create an implicit conversion from `int` to `BigInt`

```
public static implicit operator BigInt(int value)
{
    return new BigInt(value);
}
```

then you only need an overload which takes a `BigInt` parameter:

```
BigInt bigInt = ...
BigInt mult = bigInt.Multiply(5);
```

Comment: Certainly. The `BigInteger` of .NET [has this operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268348.aspx) and a lot of similar ones. They also overload the `*` (multiply) operator, of course. Note that the `BigInteger` is a `struct`, not a `class`. They chose that even if a `BigInteger` can potentially occupy millions of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

How about just implementing each int overload in terms of the BigInt one?:

```
public BigInt Multiply(int a)
{
    return Multiply(new BigInt(a));
}
```

Comment: seems feasible. But still I have to have 2 of each function, right? are they called "overload"s? What if I just want to see "public BigInt Multiply" line just once? is it too much to ask? :)